# Python Django, struggling to create a dynamic list

Tags: python, html, django, dynamic

I want to create a section on my site, where for each subject, links to corresponding past papers can be found, but I am struggling to get any output. Looking for ideas:

My views.py:

```
def index(request):
    subjects = Subject.objects.all()
    context = {'subjects': subjects}
    return render(request, 'alevelspastpapers/index.html', context=context)
```

My models.py:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

class past_paper(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam_date = models.DateField('Examination Date')
    paper_number = models.IntegerField('Paper Number: ')
    paper_urllink = models.TextField()
    markscheme_urllink = models.TextField()
    solved_paperslink = models.TextField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.subject} Paper {self.paper_number}, {self.exam_date}"
```

My html content:

```
{% if subjects %} {% for subject in subjects %}
      <p>{{ subject.subject }}</p>
      {% for papers in subject.subject.past_papers_set.all %}
      <p>{{ papers.paper_urllink }}</p>
      {%endfor%} {% endfor %} {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for subject in subjects %}
    <p>{{ subject.subject }}</p>
    {% for past_paper in subject.past_paper_set.all %}
       <p> {{ past_paper.paper_urllink }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

For better performance you can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) which fetch related objects in just one query like this:

```
def index(request):
    subjects = Subject.objects.all().select_related()
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: yep this worked, thanks!

Comment: @RayyanS I have edited answer to increase performance check

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{% for papers in subject.subject.past_papers_set.all %}` with `{% for papers in subject.past_papers_set.all() %}`

Comment: with this I get following error: 
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'subject.past_papers_set.all()'